Running a background process in multiple steps on Windows
In the job I have below, I'm trying to start a server locally in one step and the connect to that server in a following step. This works fine on Linux, but on Windows it looks like all background processes are killed before next step is executed. It fails on the step named Connect to server again (Windows).
Is there any workaround for this?

name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  micro-server:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Create index.html
        run: echo "<h1>Hello world!</h1>" > index.html

      - name: Install dotnet-serve
        run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-serve

      - name: Start server and connect to server (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
            $env:RUNNER_TRACKING_ID=""
            $web = Start-Job { dotnet serve --port 5100 } -WorkingDirectory $pwd
            
            $timeout = 30
            $startTime = Get-Date

            do {
                $elapsedTime = (Get-Date) - $startTime
                if ($elapsedTime.TotalSeconds -ge $timeout) {
                    Write-Host "Timeout reached. Server not available after $($elapsedTime.TotalSeconds) seconds."
                    exit 1
                }

                try {
                    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:5100" -UseBasicParsing -Method Head -TimeoutSec 2
                    $serverAvailable = $response.StatusCode -eq 200
                } catch {
                    $serverAvailable = $false
                }

                if (-not $serverAvailable) {
                    Write-Host "Waiting for server to become available... Elapsed time: $($elapsedTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss'))"
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1  # Wait for 1 second before checking again
                }
            } while (-not $serverAvailable)

            $totalWaitTime = (Get-Date) - $startTime
            Write-Host "Server is now available after $($totalWaitTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss'))."

            Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Modules.FileName -like "*dotnet*" }

      - name: List dotnet processes (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
            Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Modules.FileName -like "*dotnet*" }

      - name: Connect to server again (Windows)
        if: ${{ matrix.os == 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:5100" -UseBasicParsing -Method Head -TimeoutSec 2

 
      - name: Start server and connect to server (Linux)
        if: ${{ matrix.os != 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
            dotnet serve --port 5100 &
            sleep 5
            curl http://localhost:5100

      - name: Connect to server again (Linux)
        if: ${{ matrix.os != 'windows-latest' }}
        run: |
            curl http://localhost:5100



The solutions seems to be to use bash also on Windows. Than the server will be available in the following steps.
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  micro-server:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Create index.html
        run: echo "<h1>Hello world!</h1>" > index.html

      - name: Install dotnet-serve
        run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-serve
 
      - name: Start server and connect to server 
        shell: bash
        run: |
            dotnet serve --port 5100 &
            BASE_URL=http://localhost:5100/
            
            timeout=30  # Timeout in seconds
            start_time=$(date +%s)  # Get current timestamp in seconds

            while true; do
                current_time=$(date +%s)
                elapsed_time=$((current_time - start_time))

                if (( elapsed_time >= timeout )); then
                    echo "Timeout reached. Server not available after $elapsed_time seconds."
                    exit 1  # Exit with non-zero status indicating failure
                fi

                # Check if server is reachable with curl
                if curl -f $BASE_URL &> /dev/null; then
                    echo "Server is now available at $BASE_URL after $elapsed_time seconds."
                    break
                else
                    echo "Waiting for server to become available at $BASE_URL... Elapsed time: $elapsed_time seconds"
                    sleep 1  # Wait for 1 second before checking again
                fi
            done

      - name: Connect to server again
        run: |
            curl http://localhost:5100

